# typeerror slice indices must be integers or none or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, list

I tired to run this program, but it would give me the above error on line 15 
the program supposed to evaluate a preorder arithmetic expressions where it takes a single expression from stdin and output the result

```
return (preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  +   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] ))
```

here is my program

```
def preOrder(lst) :
        if len(lst) == 3 :
            if lst[0] == '+' :
                return lst[1] + lst[2]
            elif lst[0] == '-' :
                return lst[1] - lst[2]
            elif lst[0] == '*' :
                return lst[1] * lst[2]
            elif lst[0] == '/' :
                return lst[1] / lst[2]
            elif lst[0] == '%' :
                return lst[1] % lst[2]
        else :
            if lst[0] == '+' :
                return (preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  +   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] ))
            elif lst[0] == '-' :
                return preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  -   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] )
            elif lst[0] == '*' :
                return preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  *   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] )
            elif lst[0] == '/' :
                return preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  /   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] )
            elif lst[0] == '%' :
                return preOrder( lst [ 1 : ( (len(lst)+1)/2) ] )  %   preOrder( lst [ (len(lst) + 1)/2 : ] )
    pre = ['+', '+', 6, 3, '-', 8, 4]
    print ("preorder:")
    print (pre)
    print (preOrder(pre))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assumption: You're running Python 3 (or Python 2 with `from __future__ import division` in effect). On Python 3, the `/` operator is "true" division, and the result, even for `int` operands, is always a `float`, which is not a valid slice index.

If you want C-like truncating division (technically, floor division, but the difference is irrelevant for positive numbers), use the `//` operator, which for `int` operands produces the rounded down result of the division as an `int`. `//` is available on Python 2 as well (with or without the `__future__` import) and can be used there to make it unambiguous that you want floor division, easing porting to Python 3.

That is, change every instance of `(len(lst)+1)/2` to `(len(lst)+1) // 2`.